# The weird load balancing on a multicore process machine

Tags: .net, load-balancing, multicore

I am analyzing some .net desktop application. I have found that code:

```
if (System.Environment.ProcessorCount > 1)
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(2);
}
else
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal;
}

Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityBoostEnabled = true;
```

I have launched this application on machine that has the multi core (4) processor:
[image]

As we can see application loads only the **second** core (see code), but at the same time I cannot do anything on my computer even so 3 cores are in idle.

What is happing??
Does it make sense to run application using the particular core?

**ADDED**

There is other application(2) that can hold the rest processor time. It works with high priority and I cannot change it's setting. So this application should be in competition with that one.

Comment: I don't know about your observed problem. But in general computation intensive threads/programs should run at normal or lower priority and never at higher priority. High priority is for stuff that's cheap on needs to run regularly/with low latency.

Comment: What is your program doing?  Accessing any memory, disk, or other IO?  The processors/cores are not the only shared resources.

Comment: Priority level 'Higher' is never recommended, unless absolutely necessary because of other applications are demanding too much. Try again without the increased priority; your system should be more responsive then. If not, something else is taking up your resources.

Comment: @CodeInChaos there is other application(2) that can hold the rest processor time. It works with high priority and I cannot change it's setting. So this application(1) should be in competition with that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your application have a main window? Is it in the foreground? If yes, no wonder since `PriorityBoostEnabled=true` will make your application's priority even higher then.

Comment: Yes, application has main window. It is a rich UI client (grids, multithreaded tasks...)